# Password validation text incorrectly displayed in unexpected language on macOS 10.15.1

Tags: password, catalina, login, apple-configurator, configuration-profiles

I have created a new password profile from Apple Configurator 2 and applied that in macOS 10.15, Catalina.

Then I did a `pwpolicy` to require new password:

`pwpolicy -a adminuser -u usertoforcechange -setpolicy "newPasswordRequired=1"`

On the login screen, the text are displayed in some weird characters, might be the language locale is broken. I verified with few other machines to confirm it is not laptop specific.

What is the workaround for this issue?

**Note:** This happens only on 10.15.1 and not on 10.15

[image: password error]

Comment: This must be a bug in 10.15.1 that needs to be fixed by Apple, and likely that you can't do anything about. It is just showing all the password requirements except the first one in Hebrew rather than the system language.